# Way of reopening connection in java.net.HttpURLConnection

Tags: android, httpurlconnection

First, I open a connection and send some data to server. Next I get a response.

```
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();

wr = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
wr.write("some text sent to server");
wr.flush();

//read the server answer
rd  = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
...
```

What I need is to repeat the whole cycle again - send data and receive answer. The problem is that if I use the same *wr* object I get the *IOException: stream closed*. And if I try to make a new object:

```
wr = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
```

I get *ProtocolException: OutputStream unavailable because request headers have already been sent!*. It doesn't matter if I disconnect and make a new connection - it is all the same.

Is there any way to reopen the connection?

And I make it on Android, but I'm not really sure if it makes any difference in this situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `url.openConnection()` again and get a new connection. `HttpURLConnection` should be smart enough to reuse the existing connection if the request is to the same host. Quote from the docs:

```
Each HttpURLConnection instance is used to make a single request but the underlying network connection to the HTTP server may be transparently shared by other instances.
```

Comment: Thank you! It turned out to be such a simple solution and obviously worked (after adding `connection.setDoOutput(true);`)