# InputStream not reading anything

Tags: java, android, servlets, urlconnection

This is my Client side code.Client sends mobile no. to the Servlet. Servlet then sends a string to the client which is to be base64 encoded by Client.Servlet then reads this encoded string from Inputstream.But it reads nothing from the Inputstream.

```
    private class SendIP extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>
{
    EditText et; 
    Integer value;
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) 
    {

        try
        {

               URL url = new URL("http://10.0.2.2:8080/New/MyServlet");
               URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
               connection.setDoOutput(true);

               et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
               number = et.getText().toString();
               OutputStreamWriter out=new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());

               out.write(number+"\n");//sending mobile no. to server
               out.flush();
               out.close();

               BufferedReader in=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader (connection.getInputStream()));
               message=in.readLine();
               str=in.readLine();//reading the string sent by server

               in.close();
               byte[]data=str.getBytes("UTF-8");
               base64=Base64.encodeToString(data, Base64.DEFAULT);//encoding the string into base64
               OutputStreamWriter out1=new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
               out1.write(base64+"\n");
               out1.flush();//sending the encoded string to server
               out1.close();
               //out.close();






        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        /*catch(IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        */
```

This is my Server side code.

```
       protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws       ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();

    try
    {
    byte buf[]=new byte[40];
    byte b[]=new byte[40];

    ServletInputStream sin=request.getInputStream();

    num=sin.readLine(buf, 0, buf.length);//reading mobile no. from client
    String message=new String(buf);
    System.out.println(message);

    //response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);

    }
        }
          }
      }
OutputStreamWriter writer=new  OutputStreamWriter(response.getOutputStream());
    res="mobile no. received";
    str="hello client";
    writer.write(res+"\n");//sending mobile number to server
    writer.write(str+"\n");//sending string to be encoded to server
    writer.flush();
    num1=sin.readLine(b,0,b.length);//reading the encoded string from client
    base64=new String(b);
    System.out.println(num1);//this prints -1
    sin.close();

    response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);

    writer.close();

    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        response.getWriter().println(e);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Three problems:

- You have set `doOutput` to `true`, but you haven't set `doInput` to `true`.
- Your server side seems to be coded for a POST request, but the client side is not setting any method type.  (It will send a GET request by default ...)
- You are not checking the `status` for the URL connection.  If the status indicates an error, then `getInputStream()` will give you an empty stream.  That might happen (for example) if the request never gets to your server-side `doPost` method ...

---

**UPDATE**

Ah ... I see what you are trying to do.

```
    OutputStreamWriter out1 = 
           new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
```

I doubt that that will work.  When you closed the original output stream, that should have closed the output side of the underlying `Socket`.  It can't be reopened.  And if it didn't close the `Socket` I would expect the `getOutputStream()` call to throw

```
    ProtocolException("Cannot write output after reading input.")
```

Basically, the `HttpURLConnection` API is not designed to work like this ...

---

What you appear to be trying to do is to implement something like "websockets" ... where the client and the server negotiate that the HTTP socket is kept open after the HTTP request and reply and is then used for "other things".  If you want to do that, you should look at the Java EE `javax.websocket` and `javax.websocket.server` packages; see [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/websocket.htm).

There are other implementations of websockets too; Google for "java websocket", and a cooperating client and server could do this in other non-standard ways.  But this is outside what the HttpURLConnection API or implementation will support.

Comment: Try a text editor :-).  Seriously dude, what you do is read what I wrote, and then read the javadocs for URLConnection and HttpURLConnection, then think, work out what the correct code should be and write / test it.  We are not here to correct your code for you.  That's *your* job ...

Comment: But my servlet is reading data from the inputstream for the first time.It is receiving the mobile number.That means the client has not set the GET request by default

Comment: Read this: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html#setRequestMethod(java.lang.String) ... note what is says about the default method.

Comment: In this question also he is trying to repeat the same cycle using URL;Connection   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9370378/way-of-reopening-connection-in-java-net-httpurlconnection/24505618?noredirect=1#comment37939169_24505618

Comment: So that means there is no way of doing it in the next cycle using URLConnection?

Comment: Not with the same URLConnection.  Of course, you can always create a new URLConnection for each "cycle".  And if you are talking about the classical HTTP request / response model of interaction, that would be a good approach.  (The protocol stack underneath URLConnection is capable of reusing the actual HTTP connection ... if the conditions are right for that.)

Comment: I created a new URL Connection and then tried sending the string but the servlet still reads NULL.

Comment: After creating a new URL Connection,am i supposed to create a new object of OutputSTREAM FOR WRITING DATA?

Comment: If you want to write data in the second request, then yes.

Comment: Okay..so when i create a new URL connection,Do i need to make some changes on the server side?

Comment: No.  Or at least, not as a consequence.  The servlet code looks like it is designed to process one request and send one response ... as it is supposed to do.

Comment: As I said before, maybe your code has other problems.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is impossible. Well thats what I think. I've never seen such a http communication before. If it would be possible it would be very interesting though.

In one 'session' you want the server to receive something from the client. Send something back. Which the client reads. And then the client sends again data which the server should read.

Comment: So how can i do this?

Comment: Well before you believe me you could try to adapt your code. Especially -as said by others- do not create two OutputStreamWriter's. And search for example code where this type of communication is done. Maybe it is possible as you write your own server.

Comment: How can i do this without creating two objects of OutputStream?After flushing i cannot use the same object

Comment: Why not? Never heard of that. After closing you mean!

Comment: After closing the outputstream object.out.close()

Comment: So why would you close it?

Comment: Ok I tried using it before closing but still my servlet cannot read the inputstream.

Comment: Your code is difficult to read and not complete. What I see is that the server only once reads a line. And if it sends it sends two lines. Your client only reads one line. We cannot see when/where the server would read more lines. Please post complete server code.

Comment: First time server reads"message"and the second time it reads "num1".It is reading message but gives -1 in case of num1

Comment: What is happening? Your client is not sending a message before it sends a number. It only sends a number. So explain better.

Comment: the "number"that client sends is the "message"that the server receives.And the client then sends"base 64"where the server is not reading anything.It should read that "base 64" but it is not.

Comment: The way you are commenting is confusing and contradictory. My next comment wil be after you posted full server code.